# Can we have Computer Modern Font in LibreOffice?

Tags: fonts

I want to make my LibreOffice have the displayed font as in latex. But I cannot find that. Will you please help me? The font I seek after is such as the font here https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/ddt.pdf

Comment: which font? Could you explain with more detail what you want?

Comment: @Aradnix: Thank you for your attention. As I know such font is called Typewriter? https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/ddt.pdf

Comment: Well, that looks like the typical `LaTeX` made document that uses the [_Computer Modern Font Family_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). Therefore, I think you pretend to use it into LibreOffice, isn't it?

Comment: @Aradnix Uh, right, I want to use Computer Modern Font in LibreOffice. Can it be done? I am always a tex user. But recently a journal that accepts my paper asks me to give them Word. I cannot but use LibreOffice, for typing mathematics gets easy.

Comment: I think it's possible. According to the link above yo can get them in [TrueType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/) or [OpenType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/) and use them as any other font. Try it.

Comment: @Aradnix: Do you know what font in LibreOfiice is the font closest to Computer Modern?

Comment: You can download latin modern roman: http://www.dailyfreefonts.com/fonts/info/5948-Latin-Modern-Roman.html and access it in libreoffice. Another source: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Roman .

Comment: @Comeseeconquer No, I don't, bout as you can see you can download them from the web.